# Dejar un valor por defecto en un ComboBox

Tags: c#

Buen día esta ocasión mi pregunta es un tanto sencilla pero olvide como realizarlo, resulta que estoy cargando un `ComboBox` con la información contenida en una `tabla`, el `Combo` se carga de manera correcta, solo que quisiera añadir a este como opcion predeterminada la leyenda "`Seleccione`" antes de todos los demas items que son cargados desde la `base de datos`, si alguién puede recordarme como hacerlo se lo agradecería muchisimo.

Adjunto el metodo que hize para poder cargar el Combo.

```
    public void CargarDepartamentos()
    {
        try
        {
            dtInfoDeptos = objValidaEmpleados.Departamentos();
            if (dtInfoDeptos.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                cmbDepartamento.DataSource = dtInfoDeptos;
                cmbDepartamento.ValueMember = "Dpto_ID";
                cmbDepartamento.DisplayMember = "Dpto_Descripcion";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Con este código lo puedes hacer

```
cmbDepartamento.Items.Insert(0, "Seleccionar");
cmbDepartamento.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Saludos,

Answer (score 2):

Bueno yo lo solucione de esta manera

```
public void CargarDepartamentos()
    {
        try
        {
            dtInfoDeptos = objValidaEmpleados.Departamentos();
            if (dtInfoDeptos.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                datatable tbl = dtInfoDeptos;
                datarow fila=tbl.newrow();
                fila["Dpto_Descripcion"]="Seleccionar";
                tbl.rows.insertat(fila,0);

                cmbDepartamento.ValueMember = "Dpto_ID";
                cmbDepartamento.DisplayMember = "Dpto_Descripcion";
                cmbDepartamento.DataSource = tbl;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Selecciona el combobox en la vista diseño.
2. Dale clic derecho propiedades.
3. Luego busca la que dice text: escribe el texto que quieras "Seleccione"

Answer (score -1):

```
ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
DomainUpDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Solo hay que agregarle `.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Answer (score -2):

En el Load del formulario:

```
cmbDepartamento.Text=("Seleccionar");
```